# Silverlight: change property of drawn object. -- should be easy & how to debug code

Tags: silverlight

Say I have a rectangle in silverlight that I created in Blend. How can I change the background fill on the object.

XAML

```
<Rectangle x:Name="Background" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="0" Height="480" Width="640">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FED40707" Offset="0.164"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FED5EB0E" Offset="0.392"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FE849AF4" Offset="0.595"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FE2C9937" Offset="0.797"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
```

### .cs file

```
Rectangle Background = new Rectangle();
string fileName = "Images/yello.png";
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(fileName, UriKind.Relative));
ImageBrush brush = new ImageBrush();
brush.ImageSource = image;
Background.Fill = brush;
Background.UpdateLayout();
```

This runs but nothing happens. Also how can I debug this code. I loaded the project file into VS 2012 but when it runs it won't stop on breakpoints.

### Also tried:

Background.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your .cs code fails as you are newing a rectangle called `Background`, that has nothing to do with the element named Background in your XAML file.

*When you name an element in a XAML file, a C# member of that name is generated in the designer file and that property is connected to the XAML element (via a search by name of the loaded XAML element tree). That means that all named elements can simply be referenced as properties in the code behind.* Take a look in your designer file to get a feel for what is going on behind the scenes.

Remove the `Rectangle Background = new Rectangle();` line and try again. You also should not need to call `Background.UpdateLayout();`

You also probably want to choose another name, rather than `Background`, for your rectangle element as that may cause confusion with the `Background` property of all `Panel` elements

There may be other problems, but best you sort out these ones first :)